# How to dispatch an action from a sibling component in react/redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have two sibling components and they are not related. For one sibling, we are getting one dispatch function as a prop and I am able to call the action to update the state. For another component, I need to update the state using the action, but I am not getting the dispatch as props. How I can update the state for the other sibling. Here I have attached the code for both siblings.

The common class called by two siblings:

```
loadLayerComponentConfig = async () => {
const { styleConfig, statusState, datasetState } = this.state;
const {
  layer,
  workSpace,
  componentConfigUpdated,
} = this.props;
 let layerComponentConfig = {};
layerComponentConfig.status = statusState;
layerComponentConfig.dataset = datasetState[statusState];

if (this.data !== undefined && JSON.stringify(this.data) !== "{}"  && this.data.workspaceLayer !== undefined) { // calling from functional component
  componentConfigUpdated(layerComponentConfig, layer.defaultStyle.id)
} else {
  componentConfigUpdated(layerComponentConfig, layer.defaultStyle.id); // calling from another sibling and it's getting  componentConfigUpdated as props
```

componentConfigUpdated is for updating the state globally.

Now this componentConfigUpdated is an action and it's passing as a prop in one sibling(component class) but for another sibling (which is a stateless functional component), it is not passing componentConfigUpdated but we need to call this componentConfigUpdated from stateless functional component. How can I do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const dispatch = useDispatch()`?

Comment: Nope it's not working